# c++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::pair<int, int>"

Tags: c++, std-pair

I am having trouble resolving this error.  I am not having any luck on Google when I search for this error.

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::pair<int, int>"

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

pair<int, int> solve(int s, int g)
{
    return s % g != 0 ? (-1, -1) : (g, s - g);
}
```

The error squiggle is under the first ***s*** in the return where it is checking...

> s % g != 0

I cannot figure out how to resolve this.  In C# this would work.

```
public static (int, int) solve(int s, int g) => s % g != 0 ? (-1, -1) : (g, s - g);
```

Comment: This could help: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)

Comment: I think you can change the () on the answer to make_pair function from c++, so the (-1,-1) will become to make_pair(-1,-1)

Comment: Also you may want to review the comma operator.

Comment: You've fallen into trap of assuming you can do things the same way in C++ as in C#.   Try `return s % g != 0 ? make_pair(-1, -1) : make_pair(g, s-g);`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(a, b)` is *not* a pair, it's an expression using the comma operator. It *evaluates* both the `a` and the `b`, but the *result* of the expression is the `b` only. That's why it's complaining that it cannot convert your *single* `int` into a `pair`.

For example:

```
d = (a++, b+=3, c);
```

will:

- add one to `a`;
- add three to `b`; and
- set `d` to whatever value `c` has.

If you want an *actual* pair, you should be using something like `std::make_pair(a, b)`. In your particular case, that would be something like:

```
return (s % g != 0) ? make_pair(-1, -1) : make_pair(g, s - g);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This cleared it up and solved my issue.